# Как вывести в шаблон временно несуществующую переменную?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular2

В angular2 в компоненте при помощи асинхронного запроса получаю объект. Значение из этого объекта нужно вывести в шаблоне. Я делаю это так:

```
<div *ngIf="task">{{ task[0]['fields']['title'] }}</div>
```

И всё ок. Но я хотел бы вместо *ngIf использовать оператор "?". Но при попытке сделать так, консоль выводит ошибки:

```
<div>{{ task[0]['fields']['title']? }}</div>
```

В чём дело? Если бы речь шла о выводе не значения объекта, а просто переменной, то я без проблем мог бы сделать так:

```
<div>{{ variable? }}</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В настоящее время компилятор Angular не поддерживает оператор ? (оператор безопасной навигации) при доступе к свойствам через квадратные скобки. Поэтому все что можно сделать это:

```
<div>{{ task[0]?.fields?.title }}</div>
```

Либо использовать тернарный оператор:

```
<div>{{ task? task[0]['fields']['title'] : '' }}</div>
```

И самый безопасный вариант:

```
<div>{{ task? task[0]?.fields?.title : '' }}</div>
```

Comment: спасибо. но последний вариант наверное всё таки вот так: <div>{{ task ? task[0]?.fields?.title : '' }}</div>